# Add "fake" model entry to admin index

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-admin

I want to add a link to the index page of the admin, where it lists the models, but I don't want to create a new model. It would be a custom view.

This is my desired result. In this case, ***Leaderboards*** should point to **/admin/leaderboards**. **Codes** and **Users** are valid models.

[image: desired result]

I tried overriding index.html page, according [to the documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGWlF.png), using the following template.

```
{% extends "admin/index.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {{ block.super }}

    <div class="app-{{ app.app_label }} module">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><a href="leaderboards">Leaderboards</a></th>
            <td></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

But this is the result:

[image: my approach]

I know that I can replace the full index.html and hardcode a specific row there, but many people don't recommend that. Is there any alternative?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.index_template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django [actually recommends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial07/#customize-the-admin-index-page) to copy-paste the **index.html** to the app folder, and hard-code links.

> On a similar note, you might want to customize the look and feel of
>   the Django admin index page.
>
> By default, it displays all the apps in **INSTALLED_APPS** that have been
>   registered with the admin application, in alphabetical order. You may
>   want to make significant changes to the layout. After all, the index
>   is probably the most important page of the admin, and it should be
>   easy to use.
>
> The template to customize is **admin/index.html**. (Do the same as with
>   **admin/base_site.html** in the previous section – copy it from the
>   default directory to your custom template directory). Edit the file,
>   and you’ll see it uses a template variable called **app_list**. That
>   variable contains every installed Django app. Instead of using that,
>   you can hard-code links to object-specific admin pages in whatever way
>   you think is best.

Comment: That is the answer.